# Redshift server closes connection after 10 minutes

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I have a statement that takes about 20 minutes to run, which is of the form:

```
create table new_table diststyle key distkey(column1) sortkey(column2) 
as (select ....);
```

When I run it using an SQL IDE or with the psql command line client, the statement executes successfully but when I run it from my Java program, the server closes the connection after 10 minutes with the following exception:

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [create table new_table diststyle key distkey(column1) sortkey(column2) as (select ....);]; 
SQL state [HY000]; error code [600001]; [Amazon](600001) The server closed the connection.; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](600001) The server closed the connection.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:419) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:538) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.abc.mypackage.MyClass.myMethod(Myclass.java:123) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](600001) The server closed the connection.
    at com.amazon.support.channels.TLSSocketChannel.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Amazon](600001) The server closed the connection.
    at com.amazon.support.channels.TLSSocketChannel.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

I'm using org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource to create connections. I've tried extending the timeout via defaultQueryTimeout, maxConnLifetimeMillis and socketTimeout but to no avail. The server keeps closing the connection after the same 10 minutes.

```
    dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUsername(dbUser);
    dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
    dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
    dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setTestOnReturn(true);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver");
    dataSource.setDefaultQueryTimeout(7200);
    dataSource.setMaxConnLifetimeMillis(7200000);
    dataSource.addConnectionProperty("socketTimeout", "7200");
```

How do I keep the connection alive for longer?

P.S. I do not have any problems establishing connections and running  queries that take less than 10 minutes to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to extend your socket timeout.

Current it is 7200ms only:

```
dataSource.addConnectionProperty("socketTimeout", "7200");
```

Comment: As mentioned in the [driver configuration options list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html), the `socketTimeout` property is read in seconds. I tried setting the value to 7200 * 1000, just in case, but then it timed out near instantly for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

check if the redshift server have a workload management policy that is timing out queries after 10 minutes.
your java code might be setting this policy

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tcpKeepAlive time to 1 min or less while getting the connection to redshift cluster.

```
               Properties props = new Properties();
               props.setProperty("user", user);
               props.setProperty("password", password);
               props.setProperty("tcpKeepAlive", "true");
               props.setProperty("TCPKeepAliveMinutes", "1");
               DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:redshift://"+endpoint+":"
               +port+"/"+database, props);
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here- I was able to make it work by writing wrappers over `BasicDataSource` and `Connection` to poll active connection with `isValid(int)` every few minutes (any frequency more than once-per-10-minutes works). In hindsight, it seems that most timeout-related properties on `BasicDataSource` apply to connections which are in the pool but are not being used. `setDefaultQueryTimeout` and `tcpKeepAlive` + `TCPKeepAliveMinutes` did not work.

P.S. It has been a while since I resolved this problem and I do not have the code for the wrappers now. Here's a brief description of the wrappers.

`WrappedConnection` class takes a `Connection` object (`conn`) and a `TimerTask` object (`timerTask`) in its constructor and implements the `Connection` interface by simply calling the methods from `conn`. `timerTask` calls `this.isValid(100)` every few minutes as long as the connection is active. `WrappedConnection.close` stops `timerTask` and then calls `conn.close`.

`WrappedBasicDataSource` implements the `DataSource` interface, redirecting methods to a `BasicDataSource` object. `BasicDataSourceWrapper.getConnection` gets a connection from the aforementioned `BasicDataSource` and generates a `WrappedConnection` using the connection and a new `TimerTask` object.

I might have missed explaining some details but this is the gist of it.